# Where does the additional 0 come from

Tags: php, function

I have been a developer for more than 5 years but this seems to be confusing and strange. I tried to use two functions having echo on each function. Then, I call those functions and echoed again. Why does this code below displays **5100** instead of **510** only? Where does the additional 0 come from?

```
<?php

function firstNum()
{
  echo 5;
}

function secondNum()
{
  echo 10;
}

echo firstNum() + secondNum(); //Output is 5100
```

Comment: To output 510 , we should use a dot instead: firstNum() . secondNum() ,and to avoid confusion before math stuffs best to check if we have integers and not something else, there is as example `intval` for that http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php

Comment: @smzapp Maybe I should ask what your intended result is.  Did you want the sum of the numbers as an integer?  Or did you want a concatenated string containing both echo'ed values?  My answer merely focusses on "_Where does the additional 0 come from?_".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is echoing `5` then `10` then the sum of `null` plus `null`.

When you don't use a `return` php will return `null` from the function call.

You mean to do this: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/o841Z))

```
function firstNum()
{
  return 5;
}

function secondNum()
{
  return 10;
}

echo firstNum() + secondNum(); //Output is 15
```

You can remove the `echo`s in the function to have a better understanding of what is returned: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/sY5ah))

```
function firstNum()
{
  //echo 5;
}

function secondNum()
{
  //echo 10;
}

var_export(firstNum());
echo "\n";
var_export(secondNum());
echo "\n";
var_export(null+null);
```

Output:

```
NULL
NULL
0
```

Comment: Good old duck typing: `null + null = '0'`.  Or is it `0`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking @TimMorton when you use `+` to perform math, php will convert null to the number `0`.  So, the result of zero plus zero is the number (not string) `0`.

Comment: More of a rhetorical comment about duck typing... and I was thinking in javascript mode :p